# Next.js Button not returning correct input

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm creating a todo list app with next.js, whenever you input anything in the input field, it goes to the console, which is correct. but whenever i click on button, the input should automatically display just like a todo list app is but this one keeps reloading, once the button is clicked, it just reloads, please help me

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Script from 'next/script'
import { useState } from 'react'



export default function FirstPost() {
const[userInput,setUserInput] =useState('')
//create state props
const[todoList,setTodoList] =useState([])
const handleChange = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();

    setUserInput = (e.target.value)
    console.log(setUserInput)
}

//handling submit
const handleSubmit =()=>{
e.preventDefault
setTodoList({
  SetUserinput,
  ...todoList

})

}

  return (
    <>
    <Head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    </Head>
 
    
    
    <h1>TodoList App</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleChange}/><button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        </form>
     <ul>
       {
       todoList.length>=1 ? todoList.map((todo,idx) =>{
         return <li key={idx}>{todo}</li>
       })
       :'Enter a Todo Item'

      }
     </ul>


        <h2>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Back to home</a>
        </Link>
      </h2>
      
      
    </>
    
  )
}
```

Comment: `() => { e.preventDefault` inside `handleSubmit` should be `(e) => { e.preventDefault()`

Comment: Another thing `SetUserinput` is not the same as `setUserInput` and `setUserInput = (e.target.value)` is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
//handling submit
const handleSubmit =()=>{
e.preventDefault
setTodoList({
  SetUserinput,
  ...todoList

})
```

Give an argument `e` to the function, you had forgotten to give parametr. Change the code to this:

```
//handling submit
    const handleSubmit =(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault
    setTodoList({
      SetUserinput,
      ...todoList
    
    })
```

Comment: I did it but still face the same thing

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to solve the error

here is the code

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Head from 'next/head'
// import Script from 'next/script'
import { useState } from 'react'



export default function Todo() {
const[userInput,setUserInput] =useState('')
//create state props
const[todoList,setTodoList] =useState([])
const handleChange = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    setUserInput(e.target.value)
    console.log(userInput)
}

//handling submit
const handleSubmit =(e)=>{

setTodoList([...todoList,{elt:userInput}])
console.log(todoList)
setUserInput(' ')
}

//delete functionality
const handleDelete =(todo)=>{
  const updatedArr = todoList.filter(todoItem=> todoList.indexOf(todoItem) != todoList.indexOf(todo) )

  setTodoList(updatedArr)
}

  return (
    <>
    <Head>
    <title>Todo List</title>
    </Head>
    <h1>TodoList App</h1>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter a todo item"value={userInput} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <button  onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
     <ul>
       {
       todoList.length>=1 ? todoList.map((todo,idx) =>{
         return <li key={idx}>{todo.elt}<button onClick ={(e) =>{
           e.preventDefault()
           handleDelete(todo)
        
        }}  >Delete</button></li>
       })
       :'Enter a Todo Item'

      }
     </ul>


        <h2>
        <Link href="/">
          <a>Back to home</a>
        </Link>
      </h2>
      
      
    </>
    
  )
}
```

A full todo list app without style